# Plugins less with Magento Theme

Tags: magento2, css, less, cli, grunt

Good morning,

I would like to know if somebody has worked with less plugins in Magento Environment?

Indeed, I met no difficulties with grunt tools, but when Magento compile all files (through setup:upgrade command by example), it doesn't find plugins defined in less files.

When I try to reach my stylesheet, it output this error

> **ParseError: Unexpected input in _functions.less on line 5, column 1**

where line 5 give

```
@plugin "plugins/index";
```

I do not know if the problem is about js extension, as Magento look for .less file only.

Thank you for your help,

Ilan

Comment: Feels like less php version is outdated :
vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Version.php

`class Less_Version{

 const version = '1.7.0.13';   // The current build number of less.php
 const less_version = '2.5.3';   // The less.js version that this build should be compatible with
    const cache_version = '253';  // The parser cache version

}`